# the default hyperlink blue focusing is not obvious, how to make blue border bolder

Tags: html

Due to my development work is based on the TV,so I chose hyperlinks to achieve the button to highlight,but the default hyperlink blue focusing is not obvious, how to make blue border bolder.

Comment: Any reason not to simply use css to make the border thicker? http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

Comment: sorry,it's not working in the TV,only hyperlinks can achieve highlight,and i don't want to use many images.

Comment: no problem. What brand of TV is it? Perhaps there's a firmware update available. Or at the least, a help-center on the manufacturer's website.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  }
```

```html
<a href="#">Click Here!</a>
```